# Dependency Injection whit NestJs

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a Service called `EventService` and another one called `DayService`, the second one has in its constructor other service:

```
  export class DayService {
       constructor(private otherService:OtherService ....
  }
```

I have to use `DayService` in `EntityService` so:

```
  export class EntityService {
     constructor(private dayService:DayService ....
  }
```

To do this I have to add `dayService` and the services present in its constructor in the `providers` list of the `EntityModule` where `EntityService` is provided.

Is there a way I can't add to the `providers` list the services present in `DayService` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would be using a Module for this.
Imagine having a module for the `DayService`. Call it DayModule. This module has it's providers and it also exports the same providers.

Then in the EntityModule you can just import the DayModule.
This way, you wouldn't have to explicitly name all the providers also in the EntityModule.

See more in the docs [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sure, I've used this solution many times, but it doesn't solve my problem because anyway I'm inserting them in the providers and therefore all the resulting problems remain.

Comment: But if you import a module, you dont need to insert that module's providers into the new module's providers. 
i mean, you import module 2 into module 1. in module 1 you dont need to mention the providers of module 2. that comes automatically with the import

Comment: You are right, technically you have answered well to my question, It's my fault that not have explained well, so I give you a thumb up.